# Font changes to default when i run the swing program

Tags: java, swing

I have manually set the font of jlabel in swing,but when i run it then the font changes to default.So i searched on stackOverflow and modified my code accordinly but nothing changed.Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.swing.UIManager;


public class Alarms extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public Alarms() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocation(200, 400);
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
                int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int sec = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                int am_pm = cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
                String day;
                if (am_pm == 1) {
                    day = "P.M";
                } else {
                    day = "A.M";
                }
                String text = hour + " : " + min + " : " + sec + " " + day;
                Clock.setText(text);
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {

    Clock = new java.awt.Label();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setAutoRequestFocus(false);
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
    setFocusableWindowState(false);
    setFont(new java.awt.Font("DS-Digital", 1, 64)); // NOI18N
    setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 55));
    setUndecorated(true);
    setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 250));
    getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    Clock.setAlignment(java.awt.Label.CENTER);
    Clock.setFont(new java.awt.Font("DS-Digital", 1, 48)); // NOI18N
    Clock.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 165, 255));
    Clock.setText("7:45:30 P.M");
    getContentPane().add(Clock, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(8, 50, 380, 150));

    pack();
}                       

public static void main(String args[]) {

    UIManager.put("Label.font", "DS-DIGITAL");
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                UIManager.put("Label.font", "DS-DIGITAL");
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Alarms.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Alarms.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Alarms.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Alarms.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Alarms().setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}                   
private java.awt.Label Clock;
```

}
This is how it should have looked like when i run it.But the font changes when i actually run the program.[image]

Can you tell me what mistake am i doing?

Comment: Is the font definitely installed?

Comment: Yes...When i'm setting it manually then i'm getting that font as an option and also in preview that font is working

Comment: I'm assuming you mean a preview from something like the netbeans IDE. I don't know what your problem is.

Comment: I have added an image to make it clear

Comment: *`Clock.setText(text);`* You're accessing GUI out of EDT. That is not allowed. Wrap it with another `EventQueue.invokeLater`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this answer (the link points you to the answer, not the question)

[Java: Altering UI fonts (Nimbus) doesn't work!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949353/java-altering-ui-fonts-nimbus-doesnt-work#answer-7672537)

Briefly, it suggests to set Nimbus LAF first and then `getDefaults()` to set the font you want. Also, try to wrap your font with `new FontUIResource(font)`.